# Explain about this statement

Tags: representation-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $T:G\to GL(V)$ be a presentation of $G$ in a vector space $V$. I have two question about two notions in this statement:

"A $V$-valued one-cocycle is a smooth map $S:G\to V$ satisfying the propert $$S(fg)=T(f)\cdot S(g)+S(f),\quad \forall f,g\in G.$$ Given a one-cocycle $S$, one defines the associated affine module as the space $V\oplus \mathbb{R}$ acted upon by the followinfg representation $\hat{T}$ of $G$: $$\hat{T}\cdot (v,\lambda):=(T(f)\cdot v+\lambda S(f),\lambda).$$ The cocycle condition ensures that $\hat{T}$ is indeed a representation. In addition, one can show that affine modules defined using different one-cocycles are equivalent iff their cocycles differ by a cobondary."

(1) What is the definition of an affine module?

(2) What is the definition of equivalent affine modules?